# AVPlayerview comes from top left corner

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm using AVPlayer to play videos. I have an issue on fullscreen mode. Video player comes from top left corner. It looks odd.

```
NSString *filePath = [self.video_Array objectAtIndex:index];
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath ofType: nil];
url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
currentItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
_playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
_playerViewController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize;
_playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
_playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = NO;
_video=[AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
_video = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:currentItem];
_playerViewController.player = _video;
[_playerViewController.player play];
[self.view addSubview:_playerViewController.view];
```

Comment: show the screen shot or relevant code in always

Comment: check the above code

Comment: try adjusting video gravity

Comment: that dint work for me

Answer (score 1):

Please refer my code which is working fine in my application,

```
 -(void)videoPlayer:(NSString *)filePath{

    playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    self.viewPlayerContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 74, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.width);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL: url];
    AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: asset];

    AVPlayer * player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem: item];
    playerViewController.player = player;
    playerViewController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [playerViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.viewPlayerContainer.bounds.size.width, self.viewPlayerContainer.bounds.size.height)];
    [playerViewController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"videoBounds" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

    playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;

    [self.viewPlayerContainer addSubview:playerViewController.view];

    [player play];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AVPlayerViewController` to play fullscreen video

```
AVPlayerViewController+Fullscreen.h

#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>

@interface AVPlayerViewController (Fullscreen)

-(void)goFullscreen;

@end
```

AVPlayerViewController+Fullscreen.m

```
#import "AVPlayerViewController+Fullscreen.h"

@implementation AVPlayerViewController (Fullscreen)



 -(void)goFullscreen {
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
       [self presentViewController:self animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

@end
```